# Pick up certain terms in multiplication

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have the following expression:

(2a + 3b)^2

when expanded, it gives

4a^2 + 9b^2 +6a*b

I want to pick up only the terms involving a* b, that is the term 6a*b. Is there an automatic way to pick up this kind of terms? (of course in the above example it is very simple, but I want it to work automatically for more complicated cases.)

Comment: Check your expansion.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to show some of the more complicated cases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Coefficient[(2 a + 3 b)^2, a b] a b
```